# How to set urls from controller action in cakephp?

Tags: url, cakephp, routes, seo

I was creating a social networking site, in that each profile page needs to show using a seo friendly url.

Now its like www.siteprof.com/profile/23
i need to add aditioanl string 'jake-web-developer' at the end of this url. result will be like **www.siteprof.com/profile/23/jake-web-developer**. I know that this can be done when we create profile links. But if someone access this profile using www.siteprof.com/profile/23 this link, can i add that previous text to the url ?

Also is there any method to add these kind of particular string into url from controller actions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look correct, by CakePHP convention, it should look like:

```
**www.siteprof.com/profiles/view/23**
```

After that you set up the profiles_controller to have the action `view($id=0,$name="")`
I don't know why that is important, but you can generate links with the name parameter and it would still work:

```
www.siteprof.com/profiles/view/23/jake-web-developer
```

If it's important to add the last string, then you should do a redirect in the view controller. Check if the $name is specified, and if it isn't, redirect to the URL with the name, although I'd advise against it since it's a performance hit.

Comment: You certainly can have www.siteprof.com/profiles/view/23/jake-web-developer and a method signature of view($id).

Cake will helpfully ignore the 'jake-web-developer' part

Comment: But what you can't have is: www.siteprof.com/profile/23/jake-web-developer. (missing "action" in url, unless the action is called "23")

Comment: this redirecting takes lot of time, please check the url of stack over flow  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926007/how-to-set-urls-from-controller-action-in-cakephp.   if you change the ID 7926007  to something else it will automatically change the associated text.

Comment: It's not "real-time" if that's what you think. Stackoverflow also refresh the page, you're just not seeing it (I see it in Opera). To make the redirect faster you have to make sure that the redirect is placed at the start of the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to put a custom redirect header in the page if the url doesn't contain the SEO friendly title which redirects to the full url

One method would be:

```
public function view($id = null, $slug = null) {

  $data = $this->Profile->findById($id);

  if ($slug == null) {

    $this->redirect(array('action'=>$view, $id, $data['Profile']['slug']));

  }

  // .. rest of view logic

}
```

Hope this helps :-)